# SQL Select statement with default values

Tags: sql

I want an SQL statement that selects all the values for 'UserA' but if the value is empty then the value from the 'Default' column should be used instead.

I have a database table that defines a number of "variables" and each of the variables contains a value for each user or a default value.

```
VarName    Default    UserA    UserB    UserC
LeftEdge        0        10      50       60
TopEdge         5       100     100      
Colour        Red              Cyan     Green
```

I don't want to set a default value for the cell, because it is likely that the default value for a row will change from time to time and it needs to change for all empty cells, not just cells that have the old default value.

I have tried to use JOINs, but I can't work out how to make it pick the default value if the cell is empty.

Does anyone know if there is a simple SQL statement that I could use, or it there a much better way of structuring the data to achieve what I want?

Comment: specifically the requirement to add a new column for each user is problematic plus the mixed datatypes with integers and strings in the same column

Comment: Is the column empty or `NULL`?

Comment: Reading your question and example code, I do not fully understand your table structure. Are you using data dictionary i.e. each parameter/variable is stored as a row, or are the parameters/variables stored as columns?

Comment: Yes I can change  the table design.  All the variables are strings.  I believe they are null.
I don't understand the table design either, a parameter is a row.

Comment: A common table would have the rows and columns vice versa, i.e. columns `LeftEdge`, `TopEdge`, and `Colour` and one row per user. Would such fixed columns suffice or do you need the attributes to be generic for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
select varname, coalesce(userA, default) as value
from t
```

This is a horrible design, if you really are mapping users to default values.  Adding a new user requires adding a new column -- which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: So should users be rows?

Comment: @CodeGorilla . . . You should probably have a separate row for each user/varname combination.

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` works for you, if it is `NULL`. The below solution can handle both `NULL` and empty string values.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN UserA = '' THEN Default 
     WHEN UserA IS NULL THEN Default
     ELSE UserA 
END AS UserA
FROM TableName
```

And needless to say, the design is very bad.